# Importing third Party Eclipse Plugin Code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to modify an existing third party Eclipse plugin. Can someone help with respect to how to import the code in Eclipse. Sorry if this question is very basic

Comment: Do you have the source code of the plugin? Modifying the class files in the distributed plugin jar file is not really possible.

Comment: Yes i have the source code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is already a complete Eclipse project (containing the .project file) use 'File > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace'. Select the root directory of the plugin and you should be able to select the project for import.